# How to group identical values and count their frequency in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that includes 2 columns

```
source_number   category
   222             cat2
   123             cat4
   111             cat1
   321             cat3
   543             cat1
   542             cat4
   333             cat1
   343             cat2
```

I edit the function based on the answer of **Amiga500**
I run the code below  :

```
s = df["category"].value_counts()
print(s)
```

## return result  :

```
cat1 1
cat1 2    
cat2 1
cat2 1
cat3 1
cat4 2
```

## expected result :

```
cat1 3    
cat2 2
cat3 1
cat4 2
```

where is the error in this statement and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have some `whitespaces` in your column. Try using `str.strip()` to  to remove leading and trailing characters (including whitespace):

```
df['category'].value_counts()
Out[364]: 
cat4     2
cat1     2
cat2     1
cat3     1
cat2     1
cat1     1

# With using str.strip()
df['category'].str.strip().value_counts()
Out[365]: 
cat1    3
cat2    2
cat4    2
cat3    1
```

Comment: this was the answer thank you yet i already did remove white spaces

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
df['cat'].value_counts()
```

edit:

Based on the dataframe now presented above, the code should be:

```
df['category'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Ideally `value_counts()` should give the count of each category. Do you mind posting your data here.

Comment: In what way is it not working. Can't do much with that feedback! (and lack of visibility of the dataframe)

Are you sure there are no spaces etc around your "cat1" entries? i.e. " cat1", "cat1 " or " cat1 "?

Comment: sorry for the late reply  there are no space between  **cat**  values

Comment: "cat" was supposed to represent your column. I had no visibility of your dataframe at the time of answering! See edit.

Comment: sorry for the mistake in writing i was write  **category**  but still the same result it did not return the correct result

Comment: That approach works for me here on dataframes of thousands of lines without missing a beat.

Try sophocles solution to see if it works. [I suspect you do have spaces or tabs around the entries]

Comment: it was the space but i already did remove the white space